# How to copy from table design from database to another vb.net access

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

The aim is when updating the application and update the access database without altering the data so update by update only the new tables or new columns so i want to copy the exact table with it's structure to the old database vb.net and access database.

what I've tried is detecting the differences between the old database and the new one by getting in combobox1 the only missed table and in combobox2 the missed columns in the old database in exact table already there in both database and get it's data type .

so i want to copy the entire table and then create only missed columns

thank you

Comment: We lack the context your question relies upon. Please add more details to your question to clarify it.

Comment: Agree with the previous comment, but if I take a stab as I think you might be half way there.  The differences you've detected, you want to save that as a DDL(Data Definition) update script (May require some manual touch up), then in the app startup, check if said script needs to be run or not, if required run it via something like the ExecuteNonQuery() method

Comment: What have you tried? You question is to vague.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built in tool to do this.
But, worse yet, there is no "generate" change scripts in Access
(Like say with SQL server).

So, how do you approach this issue? What do some of the accounting systems or commercial programs that use ms-access as the database?

Well, you have to build a kind of "up-grade" system in your software.

This means two things:

To add a new column to a table (for example), you NEVER go open up the access database with access, but "add" or "write" the code to add that field in question.

In fact, I had an applcation deployed out in the field - many desktops.

So, I had a code module called upgrade. And each time I needed a new field or whatever, then I would write the code to add that new colum.

AS LONG as I always added things into that code module, I was ok. (never break the rule for adding new fields, tables or even increasing the length of some field? - use code).

And it became quite easy after I had some code written. I would in fact often cut + paste a previous bit of code to add a new column to a table.

However, after about 5 years, that messy code module had 800+ lines of code in it!!!

But, I ALSO realized that MOST things like adding a new column or whatever? Same code over and over.

So, what I did next was built a "upgrade" table. It looked like this:

```
 Version     action      SQL            RunCode
 2.5         AddTable    tblCustomers
 2.5         AddField    "sql here to add table"
```

etc. etc.

So, I had a version number, and then I compare against the up-grade table. I had "action", and the code would simple loop this table, and do whatever.

So, for example, to add a field, you can use access "DDL" command (data definition commands - most SQL systems support this, and so does Access).

so, say like this:

```
  ' any new table code goes here:
  If lngVer < 1148 Then
     ' add event Invoice text option
     ExecuteSQLNR "ALTER TABLE dbo.Events ADD InvoiceText ntext NULL"
     ExecuteSQLNR "ALTER TABLE dbo.Events ADD HideEventDate bit NULL default 0"
```

Or, say to increase a column lengh from 50 to 55

```
  db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblGroupRemind ALTER COLUMN Anotes text(255)", dbFailOnError
```

As noted, since oh so many the commands were VERY similar, then I started putting that information into a table, and then I would execute the required upgrades in a loop.

For a whole new table? Well, I thought that was too much code, so I always included a blank empty database - and for new tables, I would place them in that upgrade.accDB table - and "transfer/copy" the table from that upgrade database to the real one. That way, I could with great ease create a whole new table, and create in Access designers, and then add/copy that table to the "upgrade.accDB" database.

As noted? The above ideas an approaches work quite well.

In fact, over time, I found it LESS hassle while coding away to add the new column or whatever LESS effort then having to open up ms-acces, and then the table, and then the designer and make the changes.

However, the BIG issue with above?

Well, you have to get all users at least upgraded to your EXISTING schema, and there is no automated tools.

in fact, before I had any automated tools? I would open up note pad, and if I added some field to some table? I would simple type into note pad that new field in such and such table is required).

Then, when on customer site, I would open up their database, and then go look at the note pad document for the list of changes I was to make. (that is what I was doing before I started automating the process - and of course it not always practical to be "on site" or have the customers database.

But, ONCE I had all of the above working?

Then during development, I would open up my "upgrade" database, add the new row and action (new table, new column, (and more).

I even had a column that defined the function to run AFTER that one command. I mean, quite often when you add a new column, or change somthing in a table, often you need to copy data, or at least process some data after you make that change.

Once you get above going?

Then you simple NEVER make changes in the data tables directly, but use your "system" for this. And that works REALLY well.

For one, a customer could open up a older data file - say one from 4 or 5 years ago. The applcation version number would be detected, and then the upgrade code would run all though the versions to update that database. (and I did this automatic on startup - so they never even knew such a upgrade had occurred).

So, you just have to make sure that for each change you make, you put that code in your upgrade system, and you are done.

But, for existing systems? You have to look at what changes you made since last deploy, and write out the "ddl" commands (the alter table SQL commands).

There is no automated way of doing this.

As  FYI?

One of the BEST and more valuable free tools in Visual Tools is the SQL server compare utility. It will not only automatic detect and tell you the changes between two SQL server databases, but will also upgrade for you. (very nice).

But, such a system is not available for Access. In fact, so valuable is that utility for SQL server, you might consider upgrading from Access to SQL server for this applcation. With that utility? I can work local, add fields, columns, tables and even stored procedures to that SQL database. When I am on site (or even by VPN), then I run that compare tool - it shows the changes, and ALSO has a button to update the target schema.

I don't know of a automated "schema" checker and updater for Access.

So, what I suggest for above ONLY works if you put such a system in place, and THEN as a developer always make your schema changes to your upgrade system, and never directly in the database with ms-access.